# Trouble compiling a simple kernel module

Tags: module, kernel

I am trying to compile a simple kernel module. I do have a fully compiled kernel and `uname -r` does in fact confirm that I am running the kernel that I compiled.

I have a small Makefile that does the work, as follows:

```
obj-m := exo1_simple_module.o
all:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
      make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The c file is named `exo1_simple_module.c`
and it is in the directory `/home/tom/work/kernel_modules`

When I run make I get an error:

> No rule to make target '/home/tome/work/kernel_modules/ex01_simple_module.c needed by /home/tom/work/kernel_modules/exo1_simple_module.o

Somehow I think that there is a switch or command option that I should be giving to gcc that is missing.

Comment: you're not compiling anywhere within the makefile (you don't reference how to get a `.c` to turn into a `.o`) and you don't have a `modules` section in your makefile so it will fail

Comment: P.S. I would edit your post to make it more legible but someone else has edited it and so other edits aren't allowed until his edits are approved/denied

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I have seen other Makefiles for kernel modules and there was no referrence on how to get a .c to turn into a .o.

obj-m+=hello.o
 
all:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build/ M=$(PWD) clean

Comment: Sorry, I did try to edit the above comment with better format but evidently lack the information to do so.

Comment: It would appear that your `clean` reference is circular (it refers to itself) and your `all` refers to `modules` which doesn't exist.

Comment: I followed the syntax in several examples that I have seen, for example:

<http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/x181.html>

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do

```
obj-m := exo1_simple_module.o
```

when the examples show

```
obj-m += exo1_simple_module.o
```

I noticed too that you removed the `shell` before the `uname -r`

Comment: Hi, None of the above mattered. I simply put the full paths in the Makefile (rendering "shell" not necessary) and I got the same result.